# Simple Android XML Parsing Task

Tags: android, xml, regex

I need to parse the following XML structure in my Android activity. I have it in String format:

```
<Cube>
  <Cube time="2012-09-20">
    <Cube currency='USD' rate='1.2954'/>
    <Cube currency='JPY' rate='101.21'/>
    <!-- More cube tags here -->
  </Cube>
</Cube>
```

Out of this I want to get an array of currency names (USD, JPY, etc) and their respective rates. Optionally, the date which appears only once in the XML document in the format specified above. Note the empty Cube tag also. There might be other weird occurrences like this as well. I only need to get Cube tags that have both currency and rate set.

Preferably using some XML parsing library and not regex, but if it resorts to that I am ready to use it as well.

Edit:
Here's what I've come up with so far. The problem is with inserting the matched elements inside an array, which I don't know how to do.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<Cube\\scurrency='(.*)'\\srate='(.*)'/>");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(currency_source);
while (matcher.find()) {
    Log.d("mine", matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: You could easily do this with a `SAXParser`, implementing the `startElement` and `endElement` methods.

Comment: You have 3 built-in solutions for parsing XML in Android: DOM -, SAX - and Pullparser

Comment: I have edited my question with the regex I have used, because I've had some issues with setting up the XML parser classes. Can you help me get the matched entries from the expression and push them into an array?

Comment: Never use regexp to parse XML

Answer (score 2):

Here is a custom handler that should get the data you want:

```java
public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private String time;
    // I would use a simple data holder object which holds a pair
    // name-value(or a HashMap)
    private ArrayList<String> currencyName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> currencyValue = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equals("Cube")) { // it's a Cube!!!
            // get the time
            if (attributes.getIndex("", "time") != -1) {
                // this Cube has the time!!!
            time = attributes.getValue(attributes.getIndex("", "time"));
            } else if (attributes.getIndex("", "currency") != -1
                && attributes.getIndex("", "rate") != -1) {
                // this Cube has both the desired values so get them!!!
                // but first see if both values are set
                String name = attributes.getValue(attributes.getIndex("",
                            "currency"));
                String value = attributes.getValue(attributes.getIndex("",
                            "rate"));
                if (name != null && value != null) {
                    currencyName.add(name);
                    currencyName.add(value);
                }
            } else {
                // this Cube doesn't have the time or both the desired values.
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then you could use it along http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Xml.html or one of the thousands tutorials out there to parse your xml `String`.